# How to start over with Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I recently replaced my Intel Macbook with an M2 Mac, using my Time Machine backup to initialize the hard drive.  That, of course, dutifully copied all the Intel code.

I had brewed onto the old system.  Today running `brew upgrade` gives me:

```
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

So of course I ran `brew bundle dump` and that didn't give me any more direction.  I'm ready to wipe the entire slate clean with something like `rm -rf xxx` and start over, but I feel like I should be choosy about `xxx`.

FWIW, `brew --version` returns:

```
Homebrew 3.6.5-10-gbde685a
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision d6fa8906828; last commit 2022-10-11
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 576798b72f; last commit 2022-10-12)
```

Any real help would be welcome (except "switch to macports").

Comment: I found this just AFTER (of course)posting this question:  https://earthly.dev/blog/homebrew-on-m1/

Comment: The blog article you cited ([Using Homebrew on M1 Mac](https://earthly.dev/blog/homebrew-on-m1/)) sounds promising.  STRONG SUGGESTION: when you get things working (and I'm confident you will, in short order), please add an "answer" describing what you needed to do.

Comment: i ended up by first running "brew bundle dump" and retaining the resulting Brewfile as a list of stuff to install later.  Then I fired up my virtual chainsaw and removed /usr/local/Cellar, /usr/local/Caskroom, and /opt/Homebrew; re-installed Homebrew, and then re-installed the items I recognized in the Brewfile.  Not too painful.  Thanks for your vote of confidence!

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that just running "brew bundle dump" is only the first step.  Follow that wit "brew bundle install --file Brewfile", as explained very clearly in earthly.dev/blog/homebrew-on-m1

Answer (score 1):

Don't rush to follow my advice, or accept my answer. Someone else may give you something better if you are patient...

---

You should be able to get a list of installed packages in the current setup then it'll be easier to install the same packages in the new one. Try this and see if it looks correct:

```
brew ls > ~/oldbrewpackages.txt
```

You need to find where your current casks and stuff are installed. Like this:

```
brew config
```

and look for `HOMEBREW_PREFIX`. Snuffle around in there and see if it looks like where all your packages are.

---

Next, I would look around for anything to do with **homebrew** in my login profiles, comment it out by putting a hash (`#`) at the start of the line, save the file and check you can still start a new Terminal without errors:

```
grep -i homebrew -/.*
```

---

Now, rather than removing all your homebrew stuff under `HOMEBREW_PREFIX`, I would try renaming it. You may need to turn off *"System Integrity Protection"* first.

Then if your **homebrew** stuff is under `/opt/homebrew`, you could do:

```
sudo mv /opt/homebrew /opt/homebrew.unused
```

Then you'll want to reboot.

Now you should be able to install a new **homebrew** without it detecting the old one... hopefully.

---

To install your previous packages in your new **homebrew**, you want:

```
brew install $(cat -/oldbrewpackages.txt)
```

---

If everything looks good and works well, make a backup and then type the command to delete your old stuff, and read it very carefully 3x before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew.unused
```